# How to get NativeScript image from resources in TypeScript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

In template I can get images like: `res:imageName`

How to get image from typescript code? Just specify full path to resource file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same in code as well. `res://image`
in your html

```
<Image [src]="getImageSource(logo_white_bg)" stretch="none" class="img-rounded p-l-15 p-r-15 p-t-15"></Image>
```

In case you want to save images in specific folder(e.g. 'logos') for ios
in your .ts file

```
getImageSource(icon: string) {
        return isAndroid ? `res://${icon}` : 'res://logos/' + icon;
    }
```